# Spring Single Sign On with the same domain

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, tomcat7, single-sign-on

I have a multiple spring based web applications (Spring 3) running on the same Tomcat server instance, I would like to implement single sign on with out using CAS or any other thing because I only have one domain so it would be a real over kill.

Now I found Tomcat's single sign on valve attribute but I really don't know how to use it with spring correctly, I found a question here about it but really not much there for it.

Is the tomcat's method the best one ? and if it is how to do it correctly ?

What I Have So Far:

I have developed an application that should handle the log in for all the applications and will be on tomcat's root, but I can't transfer data between my applications.

Is there a way to make this application the center one ?

I am using MySQL,Hibernate,Tomcat,Spring MVC,Spring Security

Comment: With any SSO, you usually use a PreAuthenticationFilter of some kind.  It basically uses some pre-existing *thing* to authenticate someone, like a HTTP header in the case of SiteMinder.  I believe what you want to look into is the J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.